# How to generate borders in the ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set that look like this. There are 5 plots that are spatialy distributed. I want to draw a distribution map that will show the variation of a variable over the experiment. I use geom_tile to do that.

```
ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y), data = check) + geom_tile(aes(fill = HJD_6))
```

Is there any way to generate the borders around each plot. I used manualy geom_vline and geom_hline but there are problems whan I have bigger design that is not as regular as in the example.

```
check <- structure(list(Yta = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 
15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
17, 18, 19, 20, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
19, 20, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 11, 12, 13, 14, 
15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
17, 18, 19, 20, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
19, 20, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 11, 12, 13, 14, 
15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
17, 18, 19, 20, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
19, 20, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 11, 12, 13, 14, 
15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
17, 18, 19, 20, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), y = c(31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 
31, 31, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 33, 33, 
33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 
34, 34, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 36, 36, 36, 36, 
36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 
38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 
39, 39, 39, 39, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 31, 31, 
31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 
32, 32, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 34, 34, 34, 34, 
34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 
36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 
37, 37, 37, 37, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 39, 39, 
39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 42, 42, 42, 42, 
42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 
44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 
45, 45, 45, 45, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 47, 47, 
47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 
48, 48, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 50, 50, 50, 50, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 
42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 
43, 43, 43, 43, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 45, 45, 
45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 
46, 46, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 48, 48, 48, 48, 
48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 
51, 51, 51, 51, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 53, 53, 
53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 
54, 54, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 56, 56, 56, 56, 
56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 
58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 
59, 59, 59, 59, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60), RAD = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L), PLANTA = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), HJD_6 = c(136L, NA, 
NA, 170L, 133L, 55L, NA, 105L, 120L, 130L, 85L, 95L, NA, NA, 
185L, 200L, 85L, 153L, 82L, 80L, 80L, NA, 110L, 130L, 222L, 150L, 
NA, 70L, 90L, 172L, NA, 177L, NA, 97L, 65L, 133L, 62L, 52L, 95L, 
190L, 154L, 55L, NA, NA, 180L, 130L, 90L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 148L, NA, NA, NA, 244L, 158L, NA, 164L, NA, NA, 224L, 
NA, NA, 139L, 140L, NA, NA, 155L, 135L, 76L, 80L, 130L, NA, NA, 
145L, NA, 75L, NA, 105L, 70L, 95L, NA, 95L, 115L, 140L, NA, NA, 
NA, 135L, NA, 75L, 98L, 132L, 100L, 105L, 112L, NA, NA, 125L, 
105L, 87L, 79L, NA, NA, NA, 165L, NA, 110L, 110L, 133L, 75L, 
52L, 117L, 70L, 155L, 130L, 180L, 187L, 110L, 90L, 60L, 120L, 
195L, 90L, 100L, 88L, NA, 90L, NA, 112L, 130L, 155L, 152L, 130L, 
73L, 122L, 142L, 130L, 150L, 108L, NA, 86L, 125L, 90L, 119L, 
125L, 206L, 100L, 95L, 40L, 160L, 222L, NA, 100L, 112L, NA, NA, 
NA, 105L, 150L, 185L, NA, NA, 163L, 135L, 115L, NA, 155L, 183L, 
NA, 126L, 122L, 150L, 140L, 134L, 80L, 213L, 152L, 63L, 75L, 
70L, NA, 115L, 98L, 106L, 130L, NA, 123L, NA, 114L, 65L, 144L, 
115L, 60L, NA, 100L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 174L, 
50L, 102L, 153L, NA, NA, 85L, 132L, 85L, NA, 72L, 177L, 115L, 
141L, 157L, 77L, 70L, NA, 115L, 90L, NA, NA, NA, 40L, NA, 115L, 
145L, 100L, 70L, 80L, 151L, 120L, NA, 55L, 200L, NA, 120L, 170L, 
185L, NA, NA, NA, 120L, 60L, NA, NA, 95L, 172L, 60L, 155L, NA, 
191L, 85L, NA, 65L, 115L, 115L, 175L, 30L, 66L, 195L, 161L, 132L, 
NA, 80L, 75L, 115L, NA, NA, 115L, 95L, 151L, 140L, 114L, 140L, 
165L, 124L, 168L, 90L, 50L, 160L, NA, 81L, 142L, 135L, 42L, 160L, 
NA, 130L, 50L, 172L, 94L, 120L, NA, 140L, NA, 145L, 120L, NA, 
NA, 170L, 187L, NA, 141L, 200L, 102L, NA, NA, 136L, NA, NA, 121L, 
NA, 60L, 175L, 140L, 175L, 195L, NA, 216L, 77L, 231L, 175L, 210L, 
180L, 175L, 260L, NA, 160L, 172L, NA, 135L, 122L, 193L, 115L, 
175L, 60L, 85L, 202L, 164L, 159L, 95L, 169L, 190L, 80L, 80L, 
120L, NA, 115L, 130L, 172L, 155L, 75L, 72L, 170L, NA, NA, 65L, 
75L, NA, NA, 190L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 75L, NA, NA, 90L, 
NA, 190L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 52L, NA, NA, NA, 90L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 93L, 130L, 109L, NA, NA, NA, 100L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 150L, NA, 202L, 161L, NA, NA, 120L, 50L, NA, 164L, NA, NA, 
120L, NA, 138L, NA, NA, 154L, 60L, 57L, 195L, 130L, 75L, NA, 
NA, NA, 54L, 95L, 59L, 65L, 52L, 72L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
67L, NA, NA, NA, 168L, NA, NA, NA, 100L, 120L, NA, 195L, 40L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -500L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("Yta", "x", "y", "RAD", "PLANTA", 
"HJD_6"))
```

Comment: Please clarify which variable in your data set (check?, df?) represents the "5 plots". Also, make your example _minimal_.

Comment: Yta stands for plot

Comment: To a certain extent, the following does what you want...and more :) `ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y), data = check) + geom_tile(aes(color = as.factor(Yta), fill = HJD_6))` See if it could be suitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea is to find the convex hull and plot the `geom_polygon`.  Drawing on [How to draw neat polygons around scatterplot regions in ggplot2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22855/126864):

```
library(plyr)
find_hull <- function(df) df[chull(df$x, df$y), ]
hulls <- ddply(check, "Yta", find_hull)
ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y), data = d) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = HJD_6), colour = "white") + 
  geom_polygon(data = hulls, aes(x = x, y = y, group = Yta), 
    colour = "red", alpha = 0)
```

You can modify `hulls` to make the border prettier, but this solution is quite specific to this example:

```
hulls <- ddply(hulls, "Yta", function(df) {
  df$x <- df$x + ifelse(df$x < mean(df$x), -.5, .5)
  df$y <- df$y + ifelse(df$y < mean(df$y), -.5, .5)
  df
})
```

[image]

Comment: I would modify the `geom_polygon` part as follows: `ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y), data = check) + 
    geom_tile(aes(fill = HJD_6), colour = "white") + 
    geom_polygon(data = hulls, aes(x = x, y = y, group = Yta, color = as.factor(Yta)), 
                alpha = 0, size = 1)
` So different Yta can be distinguished.

Comment: @Weihuang Wong do you know how to change `ddply` that the function is compatible with `dplyr`